# Automated testing the EF model-building process

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, automated-tests

I'm doing some complex modifications to our EF model (we're using code-first) and I know it should affect my database in particular and testable ways; for instance, I should be able to assert;

```
The db will have an 'Item' table
'Item' will have an integer 'Id' field which is the primary key
'Item' will have a 50-character string 'Name' field
```

These are ripe for unit testing, but I can't find a way to test these kinds of assertion.

What I'd like is a way to get the database model from the `DbContext`, so that I can do something like;

```
var model = BuildModel(MyEntityContext);

var itemTable = model.Db.Tables["Item"]

Assert.IsNotNull(itemTable);
Assert.IsTrue(itemTable.Columns["Id"] != null);
Assert.IsTrue(itemTable.Columns["Name"] != null);
Assert.IsTrue(itemTable.Columns["Name"].Length == 50);
...
```

Does anyone know of a way to get hold of a description of the database structure implied by a `DbContext` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could start with something like this...see if this takes you anywhere.

```cs
using(ObjectContext context = new ObjectContext())  
{
var queryResult = from meta in context.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.CSpace)
                  .Where(m => m.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType)
                  from p in (meta as EntityType).Properties
                  .Where(p => p.DeclaringType.Name == context.GetType().Name
                  && p.Name == PropertyName
                  Select new {Length = p.TypeUsage.Facets["MaxLength"].Value, Name=p.TypeUsage.Facets["Name"].Value, p.TypeUsage.Facets["FacetType"].Value 
}
```

(@steve-cooper) A really helpful start! thanks. I've come up with a working class based closely on your suggestion -- I've stuck it here so I can give you the accepted answer, and so others can see the worked-up code.

```cs
    public class ModelSummary
    {
        public Dictionary<string, System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntityType> Entities { get; private set; }

        public static ModelSummary Load(DbContext context)
        {
              var adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)context;
              var objectContext = adapter.ObjectContext;

                var summary = new ModelSummary();

              var items = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.SSpace);

              summary.Entities =
                objectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.SSpace)
                .OfType<EntityType>()
                .ToDictionary(et => et.Name);

            return summary;

        }

        public bool EntityExists(string entityName)
        {
            return this.Entities.ContainsKey(entityName);
        }

        public bool EntityHasProperty(string entityName, string propertyName)
        {
            if (!EntityExists(entityName))
            {
                return false;
            }

            var entity = this.Entities[entityName];

            return entity.Properties.Contains(propertyName);
        }
    }
```

And the test looks like this;

```
    [Test]
    public void Context_SchemaIsExpected()
    {
        var summary = ModelSummary.Load(new MyContext());
        Assert.IsTrue(summary.EntityExists("Item"));
        Assert.IsTrue(summary.EntityHasProperty("Item", "Id"));
    }
```